# can I somehow disable the "lag" in the mdi parent form?

Tags: c#, forms, mdi

I have the following problem:
I have set a background image to the parent form. And every time I open a child and move it somewhere, the parent redraw the bgimage, or reload it and because this it looks like lagging. Can I somehow disable this effect?

Comment: Have you tried enabling the `DoubleBuffered` property on the form(s)?

Comment: Nope, but I'll give it a shot. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: It doesn't help, isn't here any other ways? The parent still redraw the bg.

Comment: May I suggest a WPF-based solution? you could integrate that in your existing winforms app using the `ElementHost`, and WPF is orders of magnitude faster than winforms.

Comment: I don't have much experience in wpf, is that impossible to render the image with gpu in winform? Or it's only possible in wpf apps? And I only have wpf user control. I guess I missed some items at installing :( .

Comment: @NeverJr no winforms doesn't support hardware acceleration. It also doesn't support many things that make coding in WPF really easy (such as `DataBinding`, `Styles`, `ControlTemplates`, `DataTemplates`, `Triggers` nor any advanced graphics capabilities. Is this a new project? winforms is pretty much deprecated and not recommended for new projects anymore. Only to maintain legacy applications

Comment: My project is a thesis for univ and I have no time to restart. Is there no way tho fix this bug in winform?

Comment: Yes there is a way... do not add any graphics to winforms. leave the background with only a solid color. As I said before, winforms doesn't support that. It's like asking a 90 year old grandpa to run the 100 meter race.

Comment: I know someone who does it :) but ok. Now I leave the form and if I will have time, I'll try the wpf. Many thanks!

Comment: @NeverJr Im sure there are 90 year old mans who are capable of doing a lot of stuff, but their (physical) capabilities can never be compared to a 20 year old olimpic runner. That's analog to comparing winforms and WPF.

Comment: @HighCore WinForms is *"Pretty much deprecated"*?? On what wild conjecture are you basing this? People have been doubting the future of WinForms since WPF first hit the scene *more than 6 years ago*. But WinForms is still very much supported, has a very active community, and some great third party component sets still in active development (DevExpress, Telerik, etc) And anyway, if we're talking wild conjecture, what do you think the future of WPF is now WinRT is on the scene? ;)

Comment: @Snixtor Everybody knows winforms is not recommended for any new projects. I can right away find at least 20 people saying that in StackOverflow and elsewhere. No matter if WinRT has come to replace WPF, all the skills earned in WPF can be ported over to WinRT, which is basically the same (XAML-based, MVVM, etc), which cannot be said of winforms. Also, I don't give "wild conjectures". I give concrete technical reasons.

Comment: @Snixtor DX and Telerik and everybody else are still doing winforms stuff because there is a large number of companies who did winforms stuff and need to maintain that. There is also a large number of companies who did D.O.S based stuff and maintain that, but that doesn't mean the thing is current. Its deprecated, the same as winforms.

Comment: @snixtor if you disagree with my idea, please give the OP a way to fix the horribly bad performance given by that deprecated framework.